# Issue while sending multiple individual emails using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, smtp, nodemailer

I have a list of Emails, and I'm trying to send an individual email to each recipient using nodeMailer. I am able to send a message to one contact and in some cases two. The error I'm facing is: `Error while sending mail: Error: Message failed: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=HE1PR05MB4779.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]`.

Although I am trying to send one email per connection this error occurs. Below is the code.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        pool: true,
        service: "Hotmail",
        auth: {
            user: "xxxxxx@hotmail.com",
            pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    });
var mailOptions = {
        from: "souleimanfadal@hotmail.com",
        to: currentEmail,
        subject: "Testing Bulk Emails",
        text: "Sample text", 
    };
    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('Error while sending mail: ' + error);`

        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
                transport.close();
        }
```

I have an array of emails, and I'm looping over the array to pass one email each time.

```
var another= require('./local.js');
var another2= require('./a.js')
var counter=0;

for (email of another2.data){
var currentEmail = another2.data[counter];

        another.data.myFunction(currentEmail);
        counter++;
}
```

And this is the resulting error when sending emails to 6 contacts:

```
Error while sending mail: Error: Message failed: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=HE1PR05MB4779.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]
Error while sending mail: Error: Message failed: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=HE1PR05MB4779.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]
Error while sending mail: Error: Message failed: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=HE1PR05MB4779.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]
Error while sending mail: Error: Message failed: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=HE1PR05MB4779.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]
Error while sending mail: Error: Message failed: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded [Hostname=HE1PR05MB4779.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]
Message sent: <5ec76009-187a-94a8-9960-bde465496ee1@hotmail.com>
```

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has introduced new Throttling limits due to which probably you are getting the error.

New throttling limit for concurrent connections that submit messages
The service has various limits to prevent abuse and to ensure fair use. An additional limit is being added. Under the new limit, up to three concurrent connections are allowed to send email messages at the same time. If an application tries to send more than three messages at the same time by using multiple connections, each connection will receive the following error message:
432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your provider allows you to only use a small amount of parallel connections. I see you set the "pool" option to "true". Try adding "maxConnections" and "maxMessages" as well.